# Не могу вывести комментарий на сайт в Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Сут в том, чтобы данные из моей таблицы comment выводились на страницу profile,но почему - то не получается, пробовал ставить related_name='comments' но выдает ошибку, помогите пожалуйста!
**В мою таблицу данные заносятся в comment.html, но не выводятся в profile.html**

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    body = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField()
```

**views.py**

```
def comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)

    return render(request, 'comment.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    body = forms.TextInput

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['name', 'body', 'email']
```

**profile.html**

```
<div class="comments_user">
  <b>{{ comment.name }}</b>  <span>{{ comment.body }}</span>
  <p>{{ comment.email}}</p>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

Comment: вы не привели код вывода profile.

Comment: добавил  теперь!

Comment: вы в шаблон ничего не передаете

Comment: а как передать? подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понимаю что именно вы хотите реализовать, но просто передать все комментарии в шаблон можно следующим способом:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    comment = Comment.objects.all()
    context = {'comment': comment}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

В шаблоне надо пройтись по всем объектам:

```
<div class="comments_user">
   {% for i in comment %}
   <b>{{ i.name }}</b>  <span>{{ i.body }}</span>
   <p>{{ i.email}}</p>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: если же вы хотите показывать только комментарии конкретного пользователя в его профиле, то вам необходимо переделывать модели - у комментария должен быть внешний ключ.

Comment: мне нужно просто передать все комментарии на страницу profile

Comment: Выполнил, вашу рекомендацию, ничего не изменилось :(

Comment: тогда этот код должен помочь

Comment: может что - то не так в файле profile.html?

Comment: Я же правильн понимаю выводят так comment.имя_обьекта_из_БД?

Comment: Да но при этом из вью мы передаем queryset. Необходима итерация по его объектам для обращения к конкретной записи.

Comment: Можете написть код, как это сделать? Я не совсем понимаю

Comment: я привел ответ с кодом